# FILE GLOB fails in INCLUDE()d file

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake 3.22.2 on Windows and have the following structure:

`go.bat`:

```
:: launch an out-of-source build, to avoid clutter; generator could be anything
@cmake -G "Visual Studio 16" -H%~dp0 -B%~dp0build
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.5)
PROJECT( mve )
INCLUDE( extensions/LookForExtensions.cmake )  # run one file via INCLUDE()
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( subprojects )                # and another via its CMakeLists.txt file
```

The two files it runs,
`subprojects/CMakeLists.txt` and
`extensions/LookForExtensions.cmake`,
both have identical content, as follows:

```
SET( here ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} )
MESSAGE( "Looking for files/directories in " ${here} ) # correct result in both cases
FILE( GLOB contents RELATIVE ${here} * )   # delivers correct results in one case but not the other
FOREACH( match ${contents} )
    MESSAGE( "* found " ${match} )
ENDFOREACH()
```

And the output, annotated by me with `#` comments, is as follows:

```
C:\cmake-trouble>go
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
Looking for files/directories in C:/cmake-trouble/extensions  # this is correct
* found ../CMakeLists.txt           # not correct
* found ../build                    # not correct
* found ../go.bat                   # not correct
* found ../subprojects              # not correct
Looking for files/directories in C:/cmake-trouble/subprojects  # this is correct
* found CMakeLists.txt    # this is correct
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/cmake-trouble/build
```

Why is `FILE( GLOB ... )` behaving so differently in the two different situations, given correct input in both cases? More importantly, how can I get it to behave correctly in `LookForExtensions.cmake` ?  It seems like `${here}` is correct but the `RELATIVE ${here}` clause is simply and unaccountably being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it.  `FILE( GLOB contents RELATIVE ${here} * )` does not mean, as I had assumed, "match the contents of `${here}` to the pattern".   It means "match the contents of *the current working directory* to the pattern, but re-express each output path relative to `${here}`". The smoking gun was the fact that the `extensions` directory itself was not reported as part of the contents of `..`

So, this:

```
FILE( GLOB contents RELATIVE "${here}" "${here}/*" )
```

does what I intended.

Comment: Yes, this is also in documentation.

Comment: @KamiCuk The doc could be improved. It says "Generate a list of files that match the <globbing-expressions> ... . If RELATIVE flag is specified, the results will be returned as relative paths to the given path."   It is completely silent about where the operation will actually be performed, so I bet I'm far from the only person to have misinterpreted RELATIVE that way.